# Проблема с обработкой данных, полученных с сервера

Tags: javascript

Изучаю XMLHttpRequest. Написал запрос на API github. Получил всех пользователей. Идея такова, я создаю пустой массив, делаю запрос на github чтобы получить всех пользователей. Потом в этот пустой массив пушу значения ключа id. И у меня получается массив из id. Потом я хочу брать id и по этому id получить уже конкретного пользователя и получить какие-нибудь свойства конкретного пользователя. Вот мой код. Проблема в том, что массив с моими id в консоль я вывожу, а вот что-нибудь сделать с ним и получить значение по индексу, перебрать различными методами не получается. Хочу получить отдельный элемент массива idArray  и получаю undefined, хотя в консоли я значения массива вижу. В чем я ошибаюсь?

```
let idArray = [];
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/users?since=0", true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status != 200) {
        alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
    } else {
        //console.log(xhr.responseText);
        const newData = xhr.responseText;
        let userData  = JSON.parse(newData);
        //console.log(userData);
        userData.forEach(function(item, i, userData) {
            //console.log(item.id);
            idArray.push(item.id);
          });
    }

}
xhr.send(null);
console.log(idArray);
for(let i = 0; i <= idArray.length-1; i++){
    alert(idArray[i]);
};
Array.isArray(idArray);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обрабатывать надо в `onload`, до этого данных нет: они просто ещё не загрузились.
А Вы пробуете работать с ними сразу после отправки запроса **до** его выполнения.

В консоли массив выводится когда уже заполнен, через время.

Answer (score 1):

Вы все делаете правильно, только данные обрабатывать нужно в onload [Вот пример, раздел XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Fetching_data)